# Idlj compiler is missing (Linux/JDK 11)

Tags: java, java-11, idl, idlj

Can't find idlj tool for compiling `.idl` files. Checked `/usr/bin` and `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-jdk`. Isn't it bundled with the JDK? How to add the idlj compiler?

P.S. I'm more of a Python guy, and don't use Java a lot. So I'm sorry if it's a dumb question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [JEP 320: Remove the Java EE and CORBA Modules](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320) the idlj compiler was removed together with other CORBA technologies. From Java 11 forward CORBA stack is no longer maintained in the JDK:

> Since the costs of maintaining CORBA support outweigh the benefits, there is no case for the Java SE Platform or the JDK to include it.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51711914/1602555) you can try replacing it with [Glassfish CORBA ORB](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/orb) project.