# Idlj.exe not found

Tags: java, netbeans, idl, idlj

when i run the idl file in the command prompt with (idlj -fall example'idl)  it show me this: 'idlj' is not recognized as an internal command

or external, an executable program or a batch file.

And when I tried to search the idlj in the bin file I didn't find it.

How to run the idl file and where to find the idlj.exe?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Idlj compiler is missing (Linux/JDK 11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911245/idlj-compiler-is-missing-linux-jdk-11)